# A recessed battery connector with curved contacts? 2.5mm pitch

Tags: batteries, connector

I'm trying to find a battery connector with curved contacts like this, so that an OEM battery with recessed contacts can slide over it in both directions. The spec is 2.5mm pitch, gold plated.

I've created this example image with the contact block surface-mounted on the other side of the board. I've not seen this but time and again I would find it useful so that I could get the battery flat on the PCB.

Can anyone recommend a component with one of these characteristics, or perhaps a keyword which I'm missing to improve search results? Nothing in the AVX or Bournes catalogues seems to fit the bill.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What kind of battery is being used and for what application? I have some recommendations but need to make sure I know what you're trying to accomplish. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Those are spring contact connectors.  Or spring contact battery connectors.  AVX has a series [MOBO series](http://www.avx.com/docs/masterpubs/mobocat.pdf) (Warning opens *.pdf).  I'm sure there are many others.

Molex calls them ["battery connectors"](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=battery_connectors&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction).

Comment: I'm specifically looking for round contacts though, as well as a connector which sits upside down on the PCB, allowing the body of the connector to sit flush with one face of the PCB (as drawn).

Comment: Well if you follow the 2nd link, you get this *.pdf http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/1050770001_sd.pdf which shows a unit that mounts to the bottom side of the board.  You'd need to provide a cutout so the connector would penetrate the board but that should do what you want.